# Create a counter based on another field

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create the following table.

Desired Table

```
ID     Coverage   Count
1      A          1
1      A          2
1      A          3
1      B          1
2      C          1
2      A          1
2      A          2
2      C          2
```

I currently have just `ID` and `coverage` in a table and need to add the `count` column. I want it to, starting at 1, count +1 for the **same Coverage under the same ID.**

In SQL it would involve grouping by `ID` and `Coverage` but I'm not sure where to start this in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `cumcount` here

```
df['Newcount']=df.groupby(['ID','Coverage']).cumcount()+1
df
Out[588]: 
   ID Coverage  Count  Newcount
0   1        A      1         1
1   1        A      2         2
2   1        A      3         3
3   1        B      1         1
4   2        C      1         1
5   2        A      1         1
6   2        A      2         2
7   2        C      2         2
```

Comment: `df`? What's a `df`?

Comment: @Wen, this solution worked but in one case it did not. If df only has one row then I get an error that df.ID not found.. why would it not just output 1 as the count for the single row?